# Animate border resize using VisualStateManager in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a border which changes size dependent on the contents (which are loaded asynchronously), is it possible to animate the resize of the border in xaml?

Comment: How about Fluid Layout ([Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801))?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have to play with scaling of the border rather than using their height and width. Please go through below link which will solve your concern.

[Animate border size](http://www.exploresilverlight.com/2012/07/animate-border-without-defining-size.html)

Cheers!
Vinod